# Amazon mount EBS

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to mount /vol to a EBS volume on an Amazon EC2 instance. I'm formatting the device to xfs, adding "/dev/sdh /vol xfs noatime 0 0" to my /etc/fstab file, making the /vol dir and mounting it and whenever I try to do anything with that volume (create a file in /vol, cd, ls, anything) or I try to run df the server just freezes.

Anyone have any idea what this might be? It's driving me crazy.

Edit: It seems to freeze after I mount, has nothing to do with doing any commands to the volume it's self.

Comment: Is the mount freezing or is the entire system freezing? Is there anything interesting at the end of a dmesg output after trying to mount it (assuming the system doesn't freeze)? Are you able to just mount the volume without using the fstab entry?

Comment: Just mounting normally freezes everything. It basically puts me at a new line when I click enter, and I can type, do whatever I want but it never does anything. It's like an infinite black hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to only be an issue with the 32 bit Debian image from elastic (http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1615&categoryID=101). Any other AMI works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which distribution you are using but I know there were sometimes issues in Ubuntu Intrepid (and possibly other releases) where XFS would behave badly if the log version was not set to 1 like this:

```
mkfs.xfs -f -l version=1 /dev/sdx
```

The default is log version 2 but this is known to cause kernel panics in older kernels.

Since I've been making the file system this way I've had no problems at all with XFS on ec2.