# Unable to use EBS volumes

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a Debian AMI that I built, its working great, but I cannot access any EBS volumes.

I have created an EBS volume and, using the EC2 control panel, I have attached it to my instance as `/dev/sdf` when I attempt to format it `mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdf` I get

```
mke2fs 1.41.3 (12-Oct-2008)
Could not stat /dev/sdf --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

Do I need to have something special installed in the AMI for this to work?

Comment: Possibly not mounting it to the correct instance, mount is still in progress, or an issue with the AMI? http://serverfault.com/questions/119368/amazon-mount-ebs

Comment: I've verified all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem is that you're missing the `/dev/sdf` device file.  To create one, run `mknod /dev/sdf b 8 80` as root.

Before that, though, check `cat /proc/partitions` and make sure that Linux detects the `sdf` drive. My (plain old non-Amazon) Debian install uses udev to automatically create device files in /dev, presumably if the kernel detected this sdf drive, udevd should have created the file already.